# Array values as assoc array keys

Tags: php, arrays

i wanted to fill an assoc array from variables from another array.

I have an array like this

```
$keys = array("key1", "key2", "key3");
```

and now i want to fill an array with these keys like this

```
$someArray["key1"]["key2"]["key3"] = "some value";
```

and of course it would work like this as well

```
$someArray[$keys[0]][$keys[1]][$keys[2]] = "some value";
```

But the number of keys may vary and they are different for each loop.
I want to translate some data in a hierarchy structure.

So I would love to do this dynamically from the $keys array.

For now I create a Json String, push the decoded Json to $someArray and use array_merge on it - but i thought there should be a more elegant way.

Thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop with a reference variable:

```
$someArray = array();
$where =& $someArray;
foreach (array_slice($keys, 0, -1) AS $key) {
    $where[$key] = array();
    $where =& $where[$key];
}
$where[$keys[count($keys)-1]] = "some value";
```

Comment: thank you so much - i had no idea what you use reference variables for so far :)